# How does netcdf write a geotraj type

Tags: netcdf4, cdf

How does netcdf write a geotraj type.

I use the python language, netcdf4 or h5py.

Data types like those in the picture.

example:
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1cAU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlEEg.png)

This is not the code I need：

```
f.createDimension('lon', 10)
lon = f.createVariable('lon', np.float64, ('lon',))
lon.standard_name = 'Longitude'
lon.long_name = 'Longitude of grid point'
lon.units = 'degrees_east'
lon[:] = np.arange(1, 10, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

"geotraj" just means netCDF data that the Panoply app has decided looks like it's structured as a trajectory or trajectories. If the dataset follows the CF convention for netCDF metadata and file structure, then see section H.4 of the [CF documentation](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.10/cf-conventions.html#trajectory-data). But Panoply may or may not recognize other trajectory data; it depends on the dataset.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your answer